# How to change terminal title without changing the prompt string?

Tags: ksh, gnome-terminal, window-title

I have customized my command prompt to display current directory with some color and full path. Now I want to set title of my window to only directory name (not full path).
Can you please advise how to achieve  that in korn shell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found to achieve this is by creating an alias to the cd.
I put the following code inside the `.profile` file which did the trick

```
xcd() { cd $*; echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename $PWD)\007"; }
alias cd='xcd'
```

Thanks a lot to Kusalananda for the solution which I was actually looking for:

```
cd() { command cd "$@"; echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"; }
```

Comment: You may get rid of the alias if you name the function `cd`. Inside the function, use `builtin cd` instead of `cd`. You can also use `"${PWD##*/}"` in place of that call to the external `basename` utility. You should also use `"$@"` instead of `$*` to transfer the arguments to the built-in `cd` properly.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, thanks for your inputs. 
I modified the cd as below, 
cd() { builtin cd $@; echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"; }
but now my alias which sets the home directory is not working. 
alias cda='cd ${TEST_DIR}/app/linux/'
running cda gives me the error:
$ cda
builtin: /test/dir/app/linux/: not found

Comment: Ok, use `command cd "$@"` instead of `builtin cd $@`.  You do need the double quotes.

Comment: and thanks for $@ and PWD## trick. I implemented those changes. Upvoted your comment. xcd() { cd $@; echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"; }
alias cd='xcd'

Comment: Awesome Kusalananda. command cd "$@"  did the trick. :) Upvoted :) Thanks a ton for taking time and helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site : [How to change the title of an xterm: examples for different shells](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-4.html)

> ksh provides little in the way of functions and expansions, so we have
>   to insert the escape string in the prompt to have it updated
>   dynamically. This example produces a title of username@hostname:
>   directory and a prompt of ksh$ .
>
> ```
> case $TERM in
>     xterm*)
>         HOST=`hostname`
>         PS1='^[]0;${USER}@${HOST}: ${PWD}^Gksh$ '
>         ;;
>     *)
>         PS1='ksh$ '
>         ;;
> esac
> ```
>
> However, $PWD produces the full directory path. We can remove the
>   prefix of $HOME/ from the directory using the ${...##...} construct.
>   We can also use ${...%%...} to truncate the hostname:
>
> ```
> HOST=`hostname`
> HOST=${HOST%%.*}
> PS1='^[]0;${USER}@${HOST}: ${PWD##${HOME}/}^Gksh$ '
> ```
>
> Note that the ^[ and ^G in the prompt string are single characters for
>   ESC and BEL (can be entered in emacs using C-q ESC and C-q C-g).

Comment: Thanks Felandral for searching this. I have already tried this, it changes the prompt string too PS1 and I am interested in changing the title to the current directory while keeping the prompt string as it is.

Comment: This works (I tried on my terminal), you just need to replace `ksh$ ` (at the end of the string) by the PS1 you want. And don't forget to use ESC and Ctrl+g to type the escape characters `^[` and `^G`.

Comment: it is not working, my PS1 string is ,export PS1=$(print '[\033[31m${PWD}\033[00m]\n$ '), I want to try the tile as just basename of PS1. Can you please advise